# Windows Phone 8 C# - Change the name of an xaml item in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have a small problem here and I don't know how to fix it myself. 
What i'm trying to do, is i want to change the image source of every item in the array (names).

This is what my code looks like now:
(the m at m.Source is where the name should go)

```
    private void Stars()
    {
        string[] LevelPick = new string[] {"Stage1Level1", "Stage1Level2", "Stage3Level3" };

        foreach (string m in LevelPick)
        {
            string Stars = appSettings[""+m+""].ToString();

            if(Stars == "0") 
            {
                BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Resources/Images/GeenSter.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                m.Source = bm; // error here
            }
            else
            {
                BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Resources/Images/GeenSter.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                m.Source = bm; // same here
            }
        }
    }
```

The error that i get is:

> 'string' does not contain a definition of 'Source'.

Does anybody know how to fix this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Error message isn't clear? Since `m` is `string`, there is no property or field called `Source`. What are you try to do exactly?

Comment: you should create a `Image`, this class has a `Source` property

Comment: @thumbmunkeys The names in the array are images:

<Image x:Name="Stage1Level1" Source="..."/> etc.

Comment: I realize that, but you assign it to a `Source` property. `string` has no such property

Comment: So you want to find XAML elements by their names? There is a [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) method which accepts a string and returns an object that can be cast into an Image in your case. Maybe this helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply have an array of your Image controls, instead of an array of their names:

```
var images = new Image[] { Stage1Level1, Stage1Level2, Stage3Level3 };
```

Now you could iterate over these images:

```
foreach (var image in images)
{
    var stars = appSettings[image.Name].ToString();

    if (stars == "0") 
    {
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(...));
    }
    ...
}
```